# gRPC between two ASP.NET Core servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, grpc, .net-6.0, grpc-c#

I want to send data between two ASP .NET 6 servers.
As I am in `c#` only, I am going `code first`, so I don't have to think about creating or maintain `.proto` files.

Fist I have a common project that defines my interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IGrpcUserHandlingService
{
    ValueTask<GrpcRegisterUserResponse> Register(GrpcRegisterUserRequest request, CallContext context = default);
}
```

as well as the classes `GrpcRegisterUserResponse` and `GrpcRegisterUserRequest` that I want to use

```
[DataContract]
public class GrpcRegisterUserRequest
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class GrpcRegisterUserResponse
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public bool SuccessCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

On the receiving server I added the following lines to `program.cs`:

```
...
builder.Services.AddScoped<IGrpcUserHandlingService, GrpcUserHandlingService>();
builder.Services.AddGrpc();
builder.Services.AddCodeFirstGrpc();
...
var app = builder.Build();
...
app.MapGrpcService<GrpcUserHandlingService>();
...
```

with my class `GrpcUserHandlingService`

```
public class GrpcUserHandlingService : IGrpcUserHandlingService
{
    public GrpcUserHandlingService(...)
    {
        ...
    }

    public async ValueTask<GrpcRegisterUserResponse> Register(GrpcRegisterUserRequest request, CallContext context = default)
    {
        var response = new GrpcRegisterUserResponse();

        try
        {
            ...
            response.SuccessCode = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.SuccessCode = false;
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

On the sending "server"(in this case the `client`) I thought a factory would be the right way in order to not create a new instance every time. My `program.cs` is extended by the following:

```
builder.Services.AddCodeFirstGrpc();
builder.Services.AddGrpcClient<IGrpcUserHandlingService>("UserHandling", x =>
{
    x.Address = serverUrl;
})
```

and the client DI injected into another class that calls the server:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IGrpcUserHandlingService _grpcUserHandlingService;

    public UserService(IGrpcUserHandlingService grpcUserHandlingService)
    {
        _grpcUserHandlingService = grpcUserHandlingService;
    }

    private async Task RegisterAtServer(RegisterMainUserModel model)
    {
        var payload = _mapper.Map<GrpcRegisterUserRequest>(model);

        try
        {
            var response = await _grpcUserHandlingService.Register(payload);
            ... error handling
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { ... }
    }
}
```

However as soon as I call the endpoint that executes the above function `RegisterAtServer` in `UserService` I get the following error:

```
HTTP POST /User/register responded 500 in 50.4366 ms
System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'Server.UserHandling.IGrpcUserHandlingService' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and all parameters of a public constructor are either registered as services or passed as arguments. Also ensure no extraneous arguments are provided.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.FindApplicableConstructor(Type instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes, ConstructorInfo& matchingConstructor, Nullable`1[]& matchingParameterMap)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(Type instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes)
   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
   at Grpc.Net.ClientFactory.Internal.DefaultClientActivator`1.get_Activator()
   at Grpc.Net.ClientFactory.Internal.DefaultClientActivator`1.CreateClient(CallInvoker callInvoker)
   at Grpc.Net.ClientFactory.Internal.DefaultGrpcClientFactory.CreateClient[TClient](String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method14(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
[21:49:13 ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'Server.UserHandling.IGrpcUserHandlingService' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and all parameters of a public constructor are either registered as services or passed as arguments. Also ensure no extraneous arguments are provided.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.FindApplicableConstructor(Type instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes, ConstructorInfo& matchingConstructor, Nullable`1[]& matchingParameterMap)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(Type instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes)
   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
   at Grpc.Net.ClientFactory.Internal.DefaultClientActivator`1.get_Activator()
   at Grpc.Net.ClientFactory.Internal.DefaultClientActivator`1.CreateClient(CallInvoker callInvoker)
   at Grpc.Net.ClientFactory.Internal.DefaultGrpcClientFactory.CreateClient[TClient](String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method14(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I understood that the client needs the interface only as it need to know what to call and what to expect. However I think the `grpc factory` is not working as I thought it would.

How can I correctly call the `server` from the `client`?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Having the same issue trying to use AddGrpcClient.

Comment: yes, this article helped me: https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net.Grpc/registerClientService

Comment: I ended up making my own implementation instead of using AddGrpcClient. Thanks for the followup.